# Are there faster way to scrape data

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I use `for` loop to scrape the table data.

https://money.rediff.com/gainers

```
values = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//a[contains(text(), 'Rainbow Foundati')]/ancestor::tr/following-sibling::*")

ls =[]
for value in values:
    ls.append(value.text)
```

`for` loop is known to be slower than vectorization calculation. Are there good functions to improve the scraping speed?

Comment: Can you share input, and expected output ?  (some clever use of `grep` might be quicker, and my xpath skills are not high enough to know what `/ancestor::tr/following-sibling::*` does do on non-xml (read: html) input....)

Comment: It is XPATH axes. You can search for it. The expected result is many rows of the table in the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get that table data would be as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_html('https://money.rediff.com/gainers')[0]
print(df)
```

Result:

```
    Company     Group   Prev Close (Rs)     Current Price (Rs)  % Change
0   Gujarat Natural Res     X   14.15   16.98   + 20.00
1   PNB Gilts Ltd.  B   67.96   81.55   + 20.00
2   Mufin Green Finance     X   57.34   68.80   + 19.99
3   Nelcast Ltd.    B   122.15  146.55  + 19.98
4   JCT Ltd.    X   2.83    3.39    + 19.79
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
1714    Dhabriya Polywood   XT  320.50  320.55  + 0.02
1715    Star Delta Trans    XT  349.95  350.00  + 0.01
1716    Perfectpac  XT  87.99   88.00   + 0.01
1717    Kotak Mahindra Bank     A   1756.35     1756.55     + 0.01
1718    AGI Infra Ltd.  X   598.90  598.95  + 0.01

1719 rows × 5 columns
```

For results containing 'Rainbow:

```
print(df[df.Company.str.contains('Rainbow')])
```

Which would result in :

```
    Company     Group   Prev Close (Rs)     Current Price (Rs)  % Change
47  Rainbow Foundati    X   10.28   11.06   + 7.59
1100    Rainbow Childrens   A   1034.85     1046.00     + 1.08
```

For Pandas docs, go [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/).

Comment: Almost as fast as: `curl -s "https://money.rediff.com/gainers" | awk "/Rainbow/,/\/tr/{ print $0 }"`, but has the advantage of being nicely formatted!